# chromedriver" binary not found. symfony Panther FROM php:8.0.2-fpm-buster

Tags: php, docker, symfony-panther

I have docker image

```
FROM php:8.0.2-fpm-buster
```

in composer

```
 "symfony/panther": "^2.0",


 "require-dev": {
        "dbrekelmans/bdi": "^1.0",
```

i run

```
composer require --dev dbrekelmans/bdi && vendor/bin/bdi
```

inside container i have

```
root@c2392b7b5478:/usr/src/app# chromium -version
Chromium 90.0.4430.212 built on Debian 10.9, running on Debian 10.8
root@c2392b7b5478:/usr/src/app# google-chrome-stable -version
Google Chrome 106.0.5249.103
```

but

```
$httpClient = \Symfony\Component\Panther\Client::createChromeClient();
```

give my

```
RuntimeException {#1085 ▼
  #message: ""chromedriver" binary not found. Install it using the package manager of your operating system or by running "composer require --dev dbrekelmans/bdi && vendor/b ▶"
```

UPDATE 1
I download

```
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=106.0.5249.61/
```

for my chrome

```
root@e752debb2a72:/usr/src/app# google-chrome -version
Google Chrome 106.0.5249.103
```

run

```
$httpClient = \Symfony\Component\Panther\Client::createChromeClient(
            $this->kernel->getProjectDir().'/bin/chromedriver'
        );
```

get error

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownErrorException {#988 ▼
  -results: array:1 [▼
    "value" => array:3 [▼
      "error" => "unknown error"
      "message" => """
        unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.


          (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)


          (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
        """
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put chromedriver manually to your image: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: i update example , still error but other

Answer (score 2):

Ok I add

```
$httpClient = \Symfony\Component\Panther\Client::createChromeClient(
            $this->kernel->getProjectDir().'/bin/chromedriver',[
                '--remote-debugging-port=9222',
                '--no-sandbox',
                '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
                '--headless'
            ]
        );
```

now work fine